# IE9 Confirmation Dialog not waiting for user input , postback happening without user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

**Code Behind**

```
btnNext.Attributes.Add("onclick", " return Confirmation(this,'" +  GetLocalResourceObject("msg").ToString() + "'); ")
```

.ASPX Page [Within javascript tags]

```
function Confirmation(source, msg) {
    var dialog = '<div class="dialog confirm">' + msg + '</div>';
    var buttons = {};
    buttons['Yes'] = function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
        var result = $(source).attr('tag');
        $('#<%=hidField.ClientID%>').val(result);
    };
    buttons['No'] = function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
    };

    $(dialog).dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: true,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        width: 'auto',
        buttons: buttons,
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        modal: true,
    });
}
```

When I click on the button, the dialog opens up, but the post back happens even without any user input. [Click Yes/No on the dialog box].

Any way to prevent the post back from happening till user clicks Yes/No on the dialog box. [IE9]

Comment: there is nothing that does a postback in the code you're showing ... where is the form?

Answer (score 1):

Your dialog is kind of `async`, as the function `Confirmation` returns immediately.
So, you cannot return whether the user will click yes or no right away.

I'd suggest the following:

1. Make your `ASP runat="server"` Button invisible (`display:none;`)
2. Put a new, `client side button` to the same place
3. on click of the client side button, call `Confirmation`
4. As a call back of selecting `yes` in the dialog, trigger a click to the invisible `ASP button`

This is probably the easiest way to have programmatic control of when the postback happens, without the user being able to call the postback directly.

Triggering the postback on selecting `Yes` would then look like this:

```
buttons['Yes'] = function() {
    $(this).dialog('close');
    var result = $(source).attr('tag');
    $('#<%=hidField.ClientID%>').val(result);
    $('#<%=btnNext.ClientID%>').click();
};
```